# calculate the difference of two times(hh:mm)AM/PM in minutes

Tags: c++

So I am trying to take 2 different times and calculate the difference and return the value in minutes.
The user will input each value at a time. Hours then minutes and then input am or pm. The problem I face is actually doing the calculations. I have the following function but it only works if both times are in am or pm and the first time is less than the second time. I need help :(

```
int ComputeTime(int hour1, int hour2, int min1, int min2, bool ampm1, bool ampm2)
{
    if (ampm1 == ampm2)
    {
        int calc1 = (hour1* 60) + min1,
            calc2 = (hour2 * 60) + min2;

        if (calc2 > calc1)
        {
            return calc2 - calc1;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your solution need to account for [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) or [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second)? Judging by the lack of timezone arguments, I'm guessing not?

Comment: @congusbongus nope just time difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems easy enough.

Firstly if the time is PM you add 12 hours (in minutes). Then if time 1 is later than time 2 you return time1 - time2.

```
// Convert time to minutes past midnight
int ConvertTimeToMinutes(int hour, int min, bool pm)
{
    if (hour == 12)
        hour = 0;
    int calc = hour*60 + min;
    if (pm)
        calc += 12*60;
    return calc;
}

// Compare times and return the absolute time difference in minutes
int ComputeTime(int hour1, int hour2, int min1, int min2, bool pm1, bool pm2)
{
    int calc1 = ConvertTimeToMinutes(hour1, min1, pm1);
    int calc2 = ConvertTimeToMinutes(hour2, min2, pm2);
    if (calc2 > calc1)
    {
        return calc2 - calc1;
    }
    else
    {
        return calc1 - calc2;
    }
}
```

Not a good idea to name a *boolean* variable ampm1, because it's completely unclear whether true means AM or PM. I've assumed that true is PM and renamed the variables accordingly.

I've also written a separate function to do the time conversion, to cut down on duplicated code.

Comment: hi so i tried it out and put 11:59am and 12:01pm and it returns 718 minutes but shouldn't it return 2 minutes?

Comment: @Mr.1.0 You're right 12pm and 12am are special cases. Twelve should count as zero, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: its almost there the paper i am looking at says time1-11:59AM and time2-12:01PM should return 2 minutes and then if i do it again time1-11:59AM and time2-11:58AM is 1439 when I did these examples with your code i got this http://i.imgur.com/Clx59sa.png 1st 1 minute and second 1438 minutes they were almost correct but they are 1 minute off and the answers are reversed haha

Comment: @Mr.1.0 I'm thinking there's a bug somewhere else in your code.

Comment: You have AM and PM mixed up. In my answer I said I was assuming that true meant PM but in your input code you have true meaning AM. You can have it like that if you want but you'll have to change my code to match. Don't see where any 'off by one' error would be coming from though.

Comment: i changed the true false for the am and pm and now it works except for when time 2 is less than time 1 see here http://i.imgur.com/nMdb2Hg.png for example 2 i got 1 minute when it should be 1438

Comment: Time 1, 11:59AM - Time 2, 11:58AM - answer 1 minute. That's correct isn't it? There is one minute between 11:59 and 11:58

Comment: Well then its clear that we have a disagreement about what a time difference is. It seems that if the start time is later than the finish time then you are supposed to add 24 hours to the finish time. Sounds like a simple enough fix for you to make.